# How to give a range in search in html and ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, jquery, sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I get data from database using SQL in ASP.NET Core. I can search area and price just giving the number but now I have to give range like 10 to 20 or etc. In search a web site zameen.com in which it exactly match with my requirements. But I do not know how to do this.

This is what I want:

[image]

My view:

```
<input list="Input.area.list"asp-for="Input.area" placeholder="Please Select area" style="height :50px; border-style:solid ;border-color: black;border-radius:5px; margin-left:20px;">
    <datalist id="Input.area.list">
        <option value="10"></option>
        <option value="12"></option>
        <option value="15"></option>
        <option value="20"></option>
        <option value="25"></option>
        <option value="30"></option>
        <option value="35"></option>
        <option value="40"></option>
        <option value="45"></option>
        <option value="50"></option>
        <option value="55"></option>
    </datalist>
</input>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(inputModel input, int PageNumber = 1)
{
    var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
    var datas = rdb.GetDataHouse();

    ViewBag.Data = datas.ToList().Take(7);
    ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count() / 6.0);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.areaunit))
    {
        data = data.Where(x => x.areaUnit == input.areaunit & x.area <= input.area & x.price <= input.price).ToList();
    }

    data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * 6).Take(6).ToList();

    var viewModel = new RentModel
            {
                Data = data,
                //SearchList =   List<string>(),
                Input = new inputModel(),
            };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create a dropdown list to select a specific range from the database for "Area"?

Comment: yes exactly have there any solution

Comment: OK. I got it. I will provide a solution about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo about it, Hope it can give you some help:

**Model:**

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Area { get; set; }
    }

public class TestViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please select a min value")]
        public string min { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a max value")]
        public string max { get; set; }
    }
```

**Action:**

```
        public IActionResult Range()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>();

            //generate some options for use to select
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10 ", Value = "10 " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "20 ", Value = "20 " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "30 ", Value = "30 " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "40 ", Value = "40 " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50 ", Value = "50 " });
            test.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "60 ", Value = "60 " });
            ViewBag.data = test;

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Range(TestViewModel model)
        {
            var result = _dbContext.testModels.Where(x => x.Area >= Int32.Parse(model.min) && x.Area<= Int32.Parse(model.max)).ToList();

           //....code......
            return View();
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model TestViewModel

<form method="post">

    <h1>Please select a Range for Area</h1>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="min" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.min" asp-items="@ViewBag.data">
                    <option value="">Please select a value</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="min" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="max" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.max" asp-items="@ViewBag.data" placeholder="Please Select area">
                    <option value="">Please select a value</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="max" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

**Note**:

You also need to set the maximum value in the drop-down list cannot be less than or equal to the minimum value. You can use javascript or fluent validation to achieve it.

Comment: its good but i want like in zameen.com kindly check my demo which i add in my question

Comment: It seems you want to use the same style as this website, To be honest, it is difficult to restore the exact same style as this website, I suggest you go to [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/) to find a suitable style

Comment: not the same style but same structure or like that

Comment: yes. It looks like some kind of plugin.

Comment: can you share me those plugins

Comment: You can access this [website](https://jquery-plugins.net/tag/dropdown) to find some plugins.